# There is the warning that the Proof General version does not match the emacs version

Tags: emacs

Warning (emacs): Proof General compiled for GNU Emacs 26.1 but running on GNU Emacs 26.2: "make clean; make" is recommended.

Where should I make clean?

Answer (score 0):

*Interpretation of the text:

Due to the fact that the current Emacs is newer than what was present as "Proof General" was created, there may be "things" in "Proof general" that cannot function together with the new Emacs. Please re-build "Proof General".*

## GENERAL information, to get to grips with what `make` is:

`make` - is a utility that programmers can use to set up "automated" `compilation` and `linking` of a software project, to produce the final executable file.

`compilation` uses a (general term) `compiler` (e.g. `gcc`)
to convert `source code` (text files, code in a programming language, e.g. `C`) into `object files` (intermediate format files that can be `linked`).

`linking` similarly uses a `linker` (e.g. gnu `ld`)
to combine user objects and linker modules from a library of standard routines (e.g. `printf` and the `c.o` startup module) into the final executable.

Generally `make` reads a `Makefile` (text, programmer's definition of how to build the project end result) and interprets the necessary portions of it to (re-)create the executable.

Often the makefile contains sets of instructions to "clean" the setup to an  "initialized" state - in preparation for a general coming `make` - which usually attempts to create the final executable.
As common is a similar set of instructions for "install"; i.e. to move the required files into system locations that allows a simple `program` (name of the project) to launch the final executable.

How to use:

1. prepare by installing the compiler and its dependencies (may be
   huge).
2. create a directory for the project, cd into it.
3. download and extract source code archive or use e.g. `git` to get
   the same from github.
4. Execute `make clean && ./configure` - to clean up, and detect OS
   settings and compiler parameters.
5. Execute `make` to attempt to create the final executable.
6. Execute `make install` to install the executable; assuming that nothing above failed.

FINALLY NOTE: The above assumes that the project is a general program written in C producing an executable file. That might not necessarily be the case, `make` may be used for other projects with similar needs.

*The 100% correctness of the above not guaranteed. ;-)*